# if-else condition based on a data frame's columns

Tags: r, if-statement

I need to create a new column (adminn_final) for the following data frame based on an if-else condition. If adminn_needs_update=TRUE, I should have adminn_final=adminn_updated; otherwise, adminn_final=adminn_cleaned. When I write the following code, I get numbers for the adminn_final column, not the corresponding values from the adminn_updated and adminn_cleaned columns. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
testing2 <- data.frame(adminn_cleaned=c("Sean","Sean"), 
adminn_needs_update=c(TRUE,FALSE), adminn_updated=c("Mike",""))

testing2$adminn_final <- with(testing2, ifelse (adminn_needs_update==TRUE, 
adminn_updated, adminn_cleaned))
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @jpp: looks like R

Comment: Yes it's R. I edited my question. This is my first time posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the `adminn_cleaned` and `adminn_updated` columns are factors. The `ifelse` statement is assigning the factor integer level to the new column rather than the character corresponding to the factor level.

To solve this, you can create the dataframe passing in the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
testing2 <- data.frame(adminn_cleaned=c("Sean","Sean"), 
                   adminn_needs_update=c(TRUE,FALSE),
                   adminn_updated=c("Mike",""),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

testing2$adminn_final <- with(testing2, ifelse (adminn_needs_update==TRUE, 
                                                adminn_updated,
                                                adminn_cleaned))

testing2

adminn_cleaned adminn_needs_update adminn_updated adminn_final
          Sean                TRUE           Mike         Mike
          Sean               FALSE                        Sean
```

Comment: Great! Always be careful with your data types. Factors can be tricky.